# Java Compiler Options to produce .exe files

Tags: java, windows, compiler-construction, gnu

What compiler (I'm using gcj 4.x) options should I use to generate an "exe" file for my java application to run in windows?

Comment: Generating exe-files from java-code is inherently a bad idea. You first loose platform idependence, and secondly, compiler-optimization might not be performed for the target machine as well as JIT-optimization will not get you, and updates for the jvm/api will not affect your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To compile the Java program MyJavaProg.java, type:

```
gcj -c -g -O MyJavaProg.java
```

To link it, use the command:

```
gcj --main=MyJavaProg -o MyJavaProg MyJavaProg.o
```

and then linking to create an executable mycxxprog.exe

```
g++ -o mycxxprog.exe mycxxprog.o
```