# How to get the code of a java exe?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

Hi,

how to get the source code of a java exe file (an simple application)?

(I know its not obfuscated)

EDIT:
Its an Exe File, not more not less, no *.jar

Comment: amphetamachine: Not in this sense, they are not the same.

Comment: I would go further and say that these two processes are completely unrelated. You may obfuscate your code after compilation or not, this is entirely optional.

Comment: Can you open the exe-file in Winzip or 7zip?

Comment: No, its a working exe, so its a working application, the only thing I know that should be write in Java

Comment: I don't see how is this exact duplicate. OP has .exe file made from java sources, not .jar. It's definitely not same type of question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first step would be to try to find program which turned the .jar into exe. After that you would need to study how that program is doing its thing and find a way to reverse it. After that, if you manage to get raw data, you'd use java decompilers.

You could take a look at this question for example and start from there: [How can I extract java exe to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar)

Here: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=243295 it's said that it could be difficult.

Comment: Good Point, I will have a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as java exe file. Do you mean by this JAR file? If so search for "java decompiler" in google. You can decompile bytecode to java code, but if code was obfuscated it will be ugly and hard to read and understand.

Comment: Im sorry, its a Exe File, written in java.

Comment: I have no idea how to extract JAR from such file. JAR must be inside this EXE, and this is sometimes done to ease launching of application under Windows - it is not a Java feature, there are some third party tools for creating such EXE and if you don't know structure of such file it can be hard to extract JAR from it.

Comment: I understand your point, but where I should begin, with what I should beginn?