# how to convert exe file to .jar file?

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract java exe to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar)

Is there a way to convert exe to jar file? for example i have an exe file that was written with java first, then i convert to jar file then exe file. Can i convert it back to jar file?  I understand that java programs can be made into an exe and there are tools to convert jar files to exe but is it possible to convert back?
I searched many sites but couldn't come up with the answer yet. Is it impossible or not? Does any one know a program to covert EXE files to JAR files, I know there are a lot to do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "convert" it, you can try to extract the JAR file which is inside, but:

1. some Java-to-EXE packagers don't actually embed JAR files into EXE files, but for example they embed .class files or use other techniques;
2. some Java-to-EXE packagers try to 'protect' the intellectual property of the developer by making it difficult to recover the JAR and/or the .class files.
3. some Java-to-EXE **compilers** do actually compile the code into an executable. So no luck.

I'd start using an EXE Resource Inspector, like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). I have to inform you that extracting resouces from an executable you didn't create yourself may be illegal, depending on the license it is released with.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of jar to exe is highly implementation dependent and so is the reverse conversion procedure.

Edit: This question has been answered here:
[How can I extract java exe to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar)