# is it possible to convert .exe file to java files

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert .exe file to java files?How to provide security to my exe file,because my remote data base server password is in one of my java files.I dont want others to view that .class file too.

I do not want others to view jar file in my exe file.

Comment: Why do you want to convert exe file java?

Comment: do you mean you want to convert.java to exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot convert an exe to a java file ( i think you mean jar file). There are such things as executable jars, but I don't think that is what you are talking about.

You are asking to convert native code to java code from an EXE, which tells me you don't fully understand exactly how java works.

Check out these questions, which ask a similar question

[how to convert exe file to .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760126/how-to-convert-exe-file-to-jar-file)