# Need to convert exe file to JAR file

Tags: java

I have one exe file, that is packed by Tool Jar2exe. Can anyone help me to Convert it to jar file or is it possible or not ? Below is the link of that file .

http://www.mediafire.com/?eh7dmuy9vxd9m3w

Comment: :i didn't work on that,but this link may be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar

Comment: I might be tempted to experiment, but that site requires log-in, and I'm not prepared to register.  Where did you get the EXE?

Comment: @user1283869:i didn't work on that,but this link may be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar

Comment: I changed Link . can you try now ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an archiving program such as 7-zip or winzip to open up the file, then extracting the .class files?

Comment: I somehow doubt the fact that 7zip can actually extract from `exe` files. :)

Comment: Sure it can - http://superuser.com/questions/57898/7zip-extracting-exe-executables-and-back-again

Comment: wow, didn`t know this. thanks for the link, i take back what i said earlier.

Comment: I have tried 7-zip its giving .class file of packer tool . not original source .

Comment: Then you'll need a decompiler of some sort - try JAD - http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Answer (score 1):

If those are truly binaries, then you are screwed and nothing else besides some serious reverse engineering is going to help you.

Chances however are that the exe file will contain the class files nicely packed together. Then just try to open it in 7-ZIP or similar and see if that works out.

Comment: i extract it with winrar but its not giving jar file its giving any  packer tool jar2 exe details of regex lab  . any other way to do ?

Comment: I don't want to extract , Actually i want this file to convert to jar file back . it can be done any advice ?

Comment: From the Jar2Exe homepage: _Another important feature to be mentioned is the ability to hide the class files and even encrypt them. The encrypted files are decrypted at run time. This prevents the code from being reverse engineered to a certain extent._ So buddy, maybe you are out of luck.

Comment: at run time any option to do this ? :(

Comment: You mean something like "grab the bytecode from JVM when it's executing"? Doubt it...

Answer (score 1):

if 7-zip doesnt work or just show libs but not main jar it means the option " hide /encrypt " was used. Hence you need to use winhex, ollydbg and ressource hacker and you'r good to go http://reverseengineeringtips.blogspot.fr/2014/12/unpacking-jar2exe-21-extracting-jar.html