# Unpack Jar file from .exe

Tags: java, jar, exe

I have a .exe file . I want to unpack the jars out of this file . This was packed using jar2exe. Can you please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: I believe 7zip will work. Give it a try.

Comment: Ohk , thanks . Will give it a try

Comment: When i am trying to unpack it, i get the encrypted class files. I am looking for jars that would have been packed in it before packing it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316701/how-can-i-extract-java-exe-to-jar

Comment: Please look at the packing i am talking about . And please look at the answer provided there