# How to make a .jar install on windows like a .exe

Tags: java, windows, jar

How can I make my Java program install on `Windows` like other windows `.exe` programs do, so that there's a link and icon on the Start Menu list of programs, which when clicked launches the application, instead of always having to launch it by clicking on the `.jar` file. I'd like my Java application to also show on the Programs and Features `(Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features)` panel, so that a user can uninstall it from that pane.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe

and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845/java-compiler-options-to-produce-exe-files

Comment: What about having it install in the windows list of installed programs (Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features) @Fast Snail?

Comment: first try `exe4j` and other programes answered in the above question .you can make a installer/wizard using this tools .i think programe will show in the Programs and Features