# Intergrating the jdk in a java application to get an autonomous java application

Tags: java

I developped my java application and I built a jar file. This jar file is executable of course only in a pc containing an installed jdk. How could I proceed to make my application autonomous.

Comment: Do you mean you want to ship the Java Runtime Environment with your code?

Comment: I want to ship the Java Developpement Kit with my code

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a way to create an executable app from your jar.
Try these:

- [How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe)
- [Java Compiler Options to produce .exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845/java-compiler-options-to-produce-exe-files)

Comment: No, I'm looking how to execute to install may application with no need of installing the jdk

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the JDK to run an already compiled java program on another computer. What you need is the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed on the target computer in order to run your code.

This tutorial shows how to do just that in a Windows environment:

[Bundle the JRE and Launch a java App](http://mark.koli.ch/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx)